# What does it mean when the product of two invertible matrices has no negative eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am currently working on the following problem:

$A, B, C$ are reversible matrices, and the eigenvalues of $AC^{-1}(\text{and}\ BC^{-1}, AB^{-1})$ are non-negative. I'm wondering for any $\alpha > 0, \beta > 0$, whether the eigenvalues of
$$ (\alpha A+ \beta B)C^{-1}$$
are also non-negative? Or is there any counter-example?

I've tried to use the SVD, but it seems helpless. I guess the meaning of the "product of two reversible matrices has no negative eigenvalues(just a description of the condition at the beginning)" may help.

Here is another attempt I've tried:
$$ (\alpha A+ \beta B)C^{-1} = \beta(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}AB^{-1} + I)BC^{-1}$$
because $AB^{-1}$ has no negative eigenvalues, so $(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}AB^{-1} + I)$ is reversible, then $(\alpha A+ \beta B)C^{-1}$ is reversible, but I still can't know whether the eigenvalues are nonnegative (just know that there is no eigenvalue equals to zero).

Comment: By "reversible" I'm assuming you mean invertible?

Comment: @BrunoB you are right.

Comment: It is not true that the product of two invertible matrices has no negative eigenvalues, because this would mean that no invertible matrix would have negative eigenvalues by applying that property to a given matrix and the identity, yet there are matrices which are invertible and have negative eigenvalues.

Comment: @BrunoB Thank you for your answer, your conclusion is correct. But I think the problem above is not exactly equal to "the product of two invertible matrices has no negative eigenvalues". If the two invertible matrices don't have any relationship (or don't have any constrains between them), your conclusion is totally right, but in the problem above, there are may some relationship between them.

Comment: I was just saying that in regards to the claim you had written in quotation marks, which is why it's a comment rather than an answer.